# creating a crop-image effect for container with scss

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a modal where I want to display a certain amount of picture in a window, but show the full picture (the overlay) in the background.

Basically if the amount of picture to be shown (the window) is 100px wide, but the picture itself is 150px wide, you'd see the picture as is in the window (`opacity: 1;`) but the overflow of the picture would be faded slightly, to give the effect that it would not be seen if the photo was cropped as is.

Right now my modal looks like this:

[image]

Its code:

```
<div>
      <div className="d-grid">
        <h4>Crop</h4>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
          Thumbnail
        </Button>
        <Modal
          show={modalShow}
          onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
          size="lg"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
          animation={false}
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Crop</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          {selectedThumb ? (
            <div>
              <Modal.Body className="crop-container">
                <div className="visible">
                  {" "}
                  <img className="pic" src={previewThumb} alt="" />
                </div>
              </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button>Crop</Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <Modal.Body>
              <div>
                You cannot crop or adjust an image that does not exist. Go back
                and upload a file, dummy.
              </div>
            </Modal.Body>
          )}
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
$width: 254.98px;
$height: 143.42px;
$channel-pic-width: 38px;
$channel-pic-height: 38px;
$title-font: 14px;
$desc-font: 12.5px;

.crop-container {
  min-height: 400px;
  // overflow: hidden;

  .visible {
    border: 5px solid red;
    aspect-ratio: $width / $height;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  .pic {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The functionality behind actually cropping the photo is not what I'm worried about right now, although I probably should. What I need now are three things:

1. A modal that will fit all content (including the overflowing picture) inside it.
2. A window (`width: 200px;  height: 100px;` -- the actual size doesn't matter as long as it's smaller than the picture)
3. Some kind of overlay to make the part of the picture that's overflowing (outside of the window dimensions) have a lower opacity than the window.

Comment: I'm still thinking of a proper demo, but you might want to investigate using a `mask-image`. Show the full image and mask the part you want slightly less visible with a shade of grey. White is fully visible and the closer to black, the less you see... White square on an greyish rectangle kind of idea. Not sure about the effect on `pointer-events`. Some JS magnifier tools use tricks like that. Move/size the white square in the mask with JS, `img` taken from hidden `canvas`.

Comment: Also check out [Crop Image on Pure (vanilla) JS](https://codepen.io/qertis/pen/RNPXee) on Codepen. That seems to showcase what you are looking for. Change the CSS values of `.crop-blur` to your needs...

Comment: this is still the opposite way I wanna go about it. For my usecase it's more annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that uses `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements on the crop window to create the crop border and the overlay.

`::before` works as the overlay for the overflowing part of image:

```
.window::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  outline: 250px solid white;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

`::after` works as the crop border on top of image:

```
.window::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  outline: 5px solid tomato;
  z-index: 75;
}
```

There are some buttons in below example to move the picture around, which are for testing only. These can be safely removed should this project choose a different approach for functionality.

The example runs in snippet for convenience:

```js
function Crop({ image, boxSizeX, boxSizeY, step }) {
  const [imgX, setImgX] = React.useState(0);
  const [imgY, setImgY] = React.useState(0);

  const imgRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [imgNatural, setImgNatural] = React.useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  const handleImageLoad = () =>
    setImgNatural({
      width: imgRef.current.naturalWidth,
      height: imgRef.current.naturalHeight,
    });

  const rangeX = imgNatural.width
    ? Math.abs((boxSizeX - imgNatural.width) / 2)
    : 100;

  const rangeY = imgNatural.height
    ? Math.abs((boxSizeY - imgNatural.height) / 2)
    : 100;

  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div
        className="window"
        style={{ width: `${boxSizeX}px`, height: `${boxSizeY}px` }}
      >
        <img
          src={image}
          alt=""
          ref={imgRef}
          onLoad={handleImageLoad}
          style={{
            transform: `translate(${imgX}px, ${imgY}px)`,
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setImgY((prev) => (prev -= step));
        }}
        disabled={imgY <= -rangeY ? true : false}
      >
        
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setImgY((prev) => (prev += step));
        }}
        disabled={imgY >= rangeY ? true : false}
      >
        
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setImgX((prev) => (prev -= step));
        }}
        disabled={imgX <= -rangeX ? true : false}
      >
        
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setImgX((prev) => (prev += step));
        }}
        disabled={imgX >= rangeX ? true : false}
      >
        
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Crop
        image={"https://picsum.photos/400/300"}
        boxSizeX={200}
        boxSizeY={200}
        step={10}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.modal {
  width: 450px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  outline: 5px solid darkseagreen;
}

.window {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.window > img {
  z-index: 25;
}

.window::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  outline: 250px solid white;
  z-index: 50;
}

.window::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  outline: 5px solid tomato;
  z-index: 75;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6px;
  z-index: 100;
}

button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

button:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 25px;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: 25px;
}

button:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 70px;
}

button:nth-of-type(4) {
  right: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [background-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode).

```js
let imageContainer = document.getElementById("image-container");
imageContainer.onmousemove = function(e) {
  let overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
  overlay.style.left = e.offsetX + "px";
  overlay.style.top = e.offsetY + "px";
};
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/533769/pexels-photo-533769.jpeg");
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay {
  position:absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-blend-mode: normal;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is sort of the opposite way I wanted, I was trying to have the window be stationary and the user to be able to move the image around within the window. Whatever is in the window ends up being cropped. Also, based on my code, how would I make the overflowing image 1) be behind the window, but 2) still be visible underneath it. Like how you have it if the overlay was positioned at the top left and didn't move.

Answer (score 0):

background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(url(' yourimg '), 0.0), rgba(url('yourimg'), 1.0));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).